# AttributeError: "AB" instance has no attribute 'tst'

Tags: python

Let me use simple examples to show my problem:

A.py

```
class Aaa
   def __init__(self):

     def tst(txt):
        print(txt)
```

I import A.py to B.py .

```
from x1.x2.A import*
```

where x1 and x1 are folders

In B.py, I do the following:

```
self.AB = Aaa()
self.AB.tst()
```

I get an error on the call "self.AB.tst()" :
AttributeError: AB instance has no attribute tst

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you have an indentation problem in the definition of your class. Add some code to __init__ method and remove one indent level in the function tst(txt)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `tst()` to be a local function, visible only to the `__init__()` handler. Try something like

```
class Aaa:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def tst(self):     # You probably want to add arguments other than "self"
        print(self)    # but then of course you need to call the method with it.
```